# Xpath query not working in Objective C using GdataXML

Tags: objective-c, xpath

I am trying to parse an xml using GdataXML

I have a query which is not working and I wonder why:

```
<address_component>
  <long_name>Mars</long_name> 
  <short_name>Mars</short_name> 
  <type>route</type> 
</address_component>
```

I want to save the long_name where the type is route and I am using this query

```
/*[name() = 'address_component']
 /*[name() = 'type' and text() = 'route']
  /*[name() = 'long_name']
```

What am I doing wrong here?

===========

Is there a way for GDataXML to parse the xml line for line?
is there a way other than running the xml a few times into an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to save the long_name where the
>   type is route

This XPath expression should work:

```
/address_component[type='route']/long_name
```

Meanning: *a `long_name` element child of an `address_component` root element having a `type` child element with `'route'` string value*.

Comment: next problem my code is: NSArray *street = [doc nodesForXPath:@"//GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[type = 'route'/long_name" error:nil]; NSLog(@"count:", [street count]); But when I run this my app crashes

Comment: @Nico: Be sure there is no typo in your code: `"//GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[type = 'route'/long_name"` should be `"//GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[type = 'route']/long_name"`. Second, is there any namespace declaration in the source XML, as `xmlns:XXX="..."`?

Comment: oh I typed it wrong but it is //GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[type = 'route']/long_name and the xmlcode is from http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=the+netherlands+mars&sensor=false

Comment: @Nico: In my test, it result in 10 `long_name` elements form all the 60. Also, you don't need the starting `//` operator, just `/`.

Comment: @Nico: I think you should ask an specific `objective-C` question with your code.

Comment: With NSXML I am going trough the xml line by line is that also possible with GDataXML?